# regarding a line of code on bit operation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

how to understand the following lines of c# code in terms of its bit operation

```
a = 15 & ( a ^ (b << 3));
```

and the bit operations in the following segment of code, especially the way to declare `uint8_t a`  and `uint8_t b`

```
  int  decode(const  void*  raw_in,  void*  raw_out,  uint32_t  password,  size_t  len) 
  { 
        ## some code here ##
        const  uint8_t*  in  =  (const  uint8_t*)raw_in; 
        uint32_t  seed  =  password  ^  0x48879c19u; 
        for  (size_t  i  =  0  ;  i  <  len;  ++i)  { 
                uint8_t a = (in[i] << 4) ^ seed;
                 uint8_t b = (((uint32_t)in[i]) << 7 ^ seed) >> 11;

  .......
```

Comment: Do you mean C (the tag and, it seems, the code) or C#?

Comment: The first is : Multiply `b` by 8, bitwise-XOR with `a`, and return the bottom four bits. Not sure what you're asking about in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 15 & ( a ^ (b << 3));
       |     |    |
       |     |    |_left shift (b's bits left shifted by 3)
       |     |
       |     |_bitwise xor (a XOR result of (b<<3) )
       |
       |_ bitwise and  ( 15 AND result of all above )
```

Similarly `>>` is right shift operator

Answer (score 0):

As for the line

```
a = 15 & ( a ^ (b << 3));
```

It takes `b` and bit-shift it right three times (if `b` is `0x01` then it becomes `0x08`). Then takes the result of that and xors with `a`. Then that result is used to bitwise and with `15` (thereby masking away everything but the lowest four bits) and assigns the result to `a`.

For the other code, I can explain exactly what it does in terms of operations, like I did above, but few here would be able to explain the *meaning* of it.

Answer (score 0):

b is an 8 bit value

b << 3 is that value shifted 3 bites to the left

This is then exclusively ORed with a. Which gives a 1 if corresponding bits are different and 0 if they are the same.

This value is then bitwise ANDed with 15 which is 00001111 so the least significant four bits stay the same and the most significant 4 are made zero.